# Calculate theoretical quantiles with calculator (qq-plot)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, quantile

Let's say we have the following data:

$-1.8, -0.82, 0.3, 1.2, 1.6$

Now I want to make a qq-plot out of it by hand, just with a calculator (Casio fc 991).

I start by sorting the values in ranks j and calculate how many observations are less than or equal to $x(j)$ by $j* = \frac{j-0.5}n$.

This brings us following values $j*$:

$0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9$

These are my sample quantiles, right? To get my qq-plot I now want to plot these against the theoretical quantiles. But here I stuck.

The theoretical quantiles are:
$-1.28, -0.52, 0.00, 0.52, 1.28$

But how do I calculate these values **without** R or any software but just with a calculator?

I got the following formula: $(\phi^{-1})(j*)$ but I simply do not understand how I should come up with those values.

Cheers and thanks for your effort!

Comment: Maybe your calculator is like the one in [this video](https://youtu.be/Xj-0m-dPyaI?t=241). Your formula requires $\Phi^{-1}(j^*)$, which is the inverse of the standard normal CDF, evaluated at argument $j^*$. (This is the value $z$ such that $j^*$ is the area below $z$ under a standard normal density, which has mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.) The video shows how to compute this with a Casio fx-991EX, by using the appropriate inputs (i.e., in your case the mean & standard deviation are input as $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, respectively, and the value of $j^*$ is input as the "Area".

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: Note: You say *"These [$j^*$ values] are my sample quantiles, right? To get my qq-plot I now want to plot these against the theoretical quantiles."*, but no, the values of $j^*$ are not the sample quantiles; rather, the $j^*$th sample quantile is (approximately) $x_{(j)}$, and the $j^*$th theoretical (standard normal) quantile is $\Phi^{-1}(j^*)$. So you want to plot $x_{(j)}$ vs. $\Phi^{-1}(j^*)$, i.e., $(−1.8,−0.82,0.3,1.2,1.6)$ vs. $(−1.28,−0.52,0.00,0.52,1.28)$ and look for a linear relationship.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Check this link https://www.statisticshowto.com/q-q-plots/